# How do I do a pin search with pinterest-node-api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, pinterest

```
import Pinterest from "pinterest-node-api";
const client = new Pinterest('pina_AMAS3KIWABUBCAA');

  try {
    // Search for pins with the keyword
    const res = await client.request('/pins', {
      method: 'GET',
      params: {
        query: `${keyword} ${modifier}`,
        fields: 'id,note,image'
      }
    });
    const pins = res.data;
  
    // Comment on each pin
    for await (const pin of pins) {
      await client.comment(pin.id, variation);
      console.log(`Commented on pin: https://pinterest.com/pin/${pin.id}`);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Failed to search for or comment on pins. Error: ${error.message}`);
  }
```

I get `client.request is not a function`

I'm trying to perform an API call to search globally for pins by keyword.

The docs on their page don't give me much confidence as none of the examples worked.

Comment: From what I can see you seem to look for the `/search/pins` endpoint documented here: https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/api/v5/#operation/search_user_boards/get. And I don't see any method in the `pinterest-node-api` library to make such a request. I think you need to go with a manual way with `fetch` or some other AJAX library

Comment: Can you give me a working fetch example? Also it looks like that endpoint requires a user ID. Is there anyway to do a global search for pins to comment on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   // Search for pins with the keyword
    const searchUrl = `https://api.pinterest.com/v5/search/pins?query=${encodeURIComponent(search)}&topic_based=true`;
    const res = await fetch(searchUrl, {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${key}`,
      },
    });

    const pins = (await res.json()).items;
```